# fit curve with lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I have a certain power spectrum array saved as `test`, depending on a frequency array `f`.

This power spectrum generally looks like in the following figure
[image]

It is to be remarked that the above power spectrum stemms from a simulated time series.

What I want to do, in principle, is to fit a curve approaching the simulated power spectrum as shown below:

[image]

I know that the theoretical power spectrum can be defined as follows:

```
function ps_theo = ps_th(L,Uhub,f)

const = L/Uhub;
f_x = 6.*f.*(L/Uhub);
exp = 5/3;
ps_theo = (4*const)./((1 + f_x).^exp);

end
```

where `L` is a constant length scale, `Uhub`, a constant speed and `f` the frequency vector.

The question is: I don't know the value of 'L', therefore I was thinking of an **optimized non-linear resolution** by using `lsqcurvefit`.

I have been proceeding as follows:

```
xdata = f;
ydata = test;
Uhub = 10;

fit_func = @(L) ps_th(L,Uhub,f);

L_opt = lsqcurvefit(@fit_func,330.2,xdata,ydata)
```

which retrieves an error msg on the number of inputs variables for the `fit_func` function.

Would you mind to shed a light?

Comment: Read the help for lsqcurvefit. Look at the examples. How does it pass in the arguments to your function? How does it optimize when there is more than one variable? THINK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're fitting can only take in two arguments.  You can rewrite `ps_th` like this:

```
function ps_theo = ps_th(x0,f)
L = x0(1);
Uhub = x0(2);

const = L/Uhub;
f_x = 6.*f.*(L/Uhub);
exp = 5/3;
ps_theo = (4*const)./((1 + f_x).^exp);

end
```

Then call lsqcurvefit with something like this:

```
x0Start = [330.2,10]; % vector of initial parameters
x0_opt = lsqcurvefit(@ps_th,x0Start,xdata,ydata);
```

Comment: I have done this already, but then also `Uhub` is being changed; only `L` is supposed to vary.

Comment: Then don't make Uhub an input argument to ps_th.

Comment: beside the variability of `Uhub` (which is undesired), the final fit is really poor.

Comment: You can try changing the initial parameters or varying the Options arguments, particularly TolFun, TolX, and MaxIter. Are you sure a good fit is possible with one varying parameter?

Comment: it should since the only parameter I want to evaluate is 'L'. I'll work around what you propose